# Cannot display variable from controller in erb file

Tags: erb

I begin learning ruby and rails this week. So I follow some tutorial in the book I found in my school library.

I get to the point where I have main_controller.rb:

```
class MainController < ApplicationController
  def welcome
    @my_var = 5
  end
end
```

and for my welcome.html.erb:

```
<h1>Welcome to the My Application</h1>
We currently have <%= @my_var %> visitors.
```

but when i run my server, all i got from localhost:3000/main/welcome is:

> Welcome to the My Application We
>   currently have visitors.

as if the everything in <%= %> was not executed.
and I also try to insert puts 'welcome method is executed' to the main_controller.rb
and it does print the line.

So any help? I thank you in advance,
Fajarmf

Answer (score 0):

Try <%=h @my_var %>

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are rendering the page before you set the instance variables

Answer (score 0):

There has no problem on your code, but when you change the code you need to refresh you browsers.